# Date Picker displaying issue in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

Am using Date Picker in my screen. But the problem is its not displaying correctly means.. see this image:

[image]
You can see there , year is cutting . Why it is happening.

**Edited:**

```
 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,  mDateSetListener,  cyear, cmonth, cday);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        // onDateSet method
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {



            //Toast.makeText(VideoPush.this, "Selected Date is ="+date_selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

When i click on textView am opening this dialog.

Comment: That's a pretty custom theme you have there. That might be the problem. Can you show the code you use to create the dialog?

Comment: Code edited please check..thanx (am not using any theme here )

Comment: What's the device? Looks like Samsung theme

Comment: Yes it is samsung galaxy tablet am using...

Comment: Is it a rotation-related issue? What happens if you run the app in a simulator?

Comment: It could be the issue of samsung theme on tablets in portrait orientation. You can try other app with standard `DatePicker` to find out is it true.

Comment: If you change the font, it still displays wrong?

Comment: Its not rotation related issue as am using nly portrait in manifest..And about font am not customizing any font here just default. Am checking in my simulator now

Comment: Heeey its displaying fully and correctly in simultor ,why it is happening in samsung device how to resolve now?

Comment: Could you downsize the DatePicker Dialog font?

Comment: Their datepicker implementation might only be able to handle landscape orientation. In which case, there's not much you can do: either drop portrait support, implement your own datepicker or send them an angry email :)

Comment: I'd send them the angry email anyway XD. Brand customization is what is damaging Android the most in my opinion.

Comment: So i thought i go for date slider :http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/ rather than this buggy thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use this than Default Date Picker :

[Date Slider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/)